# Please Suggest better characters

Tags: games

Please Suggest better characters for the aliens

[image]

Just edit the text below:

1310     :9999
凸X3

令令令令令令令令令令令
吳吳吳吳吳吳吳吳吳
吳吳吳吳吳吳吳吳  v
黑黑黑黑黑黑黑    v
黑  l 黑黑黑  l
l *       l    l
l  !      l     l
l   !     l
!
凹   !凹    凹    凹
凸

Comment: nostalgia lah  but the game has 5 x 11 invaders https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I made a similar graphic on another forum but can't find it now so I have to make one again

Comment: Ha ha ha cool :)

Answer (score 2):

to simulate the arcade game [space invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders)

`中中中中中中中中中中中　　
　　屮屮屮屮屮屮屮屮屮屮屮　
　　艸艸艸艸艸艸艸艸艸艸艸　　
　　芔芔芔芔芔芔芔芔芔芔芔　　
　　茻茻茻茻茻茻茻茻茻茻茻　　
　　| 　　　　　　　　　　　　
　　　　　　|　　| 　　　　　
　　　　　　　　　　| 　　　　
　　　凹⋮　凹　　凹　　凹　　　
　　　　凸`

[image]

Comment: But the second and third rows have the same kind of aliens

Comment: @TangHo, sorry lah  edited. basically, my initial association is 中 + 屮艸芔茻 

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting superimposed words. ([叠字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-sg/%E7%96%8A%E5%AD%97))

```
           卌卌卌卌卌卌卌卌卌卌卌
           卅卅卅卅卅卅卅卅卅卅卅
森森森森森森森森森森森           卄卄卄卄卄卄卄卄卄卄卄
林林林林林林林林林林林           十十十十十十十十十十十
木木木木木木木木木木木           一一一一一一一一一一一
    |                                        ¦         
     |                                      ¦        
        |                               ¦      
  凹  凹 | 凹   凹              曱   曱 ¦  曱   曱 
         凸                           甴
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1310     :9999
凸X3

念念念念念念念念念念念
蟹蟹蟹蟹蟹蟹蟹蟹
蟹蟹蟹蟹蟹蟹蟹  v
黑黑黑黑黑黑黑 v
黑  l 黑黑黑  l
l *       l   l
l  !      l   l
l   !     l
!
凹  ! 凹    凹    凹
凸